# Can I still use abstract method if one of the method parameters is different?

Tags: python

In the code below, I have 3 subclasses, Model1, Model2, Model3. For the 'exec' method, if Model1 and Model2 have only  'text' as parameter, but Model3 has one additional parameter 'type'. In this case, can I still define 'exec' as the abstract method, or I shouldn't define it as an abstract method?

```
class Model(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def exec(self, text):
        pass
```

Comment: The idea of an abstract method is you can call it without concern for which implementation is executed. If you have to know which one it is so you can pass the appropriate arguments, then I don't see what the abstract method benefits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the logic.

If the `type` parameter is related to all `Model` objects, so you can create an `abstractmethod` of it for all of them:

```py
class Model(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def exec(self, text, type=None):
        pass
```

But, IMO if `type` param is not related to all `Model` objects, you cannot write an `abstractmethod` for it.

Comment: 'type' will only be used by Model3 for sure. But the type=None seems to allow it to be defined as abstract. Why you say 'you cannot write an abstractmethod for it'?

Comment: @marlon Because an `abstractmethod` is for the greater good! Not only to reduce lines of code. an `abstractmethod` should have a shared logic and signature among all of its users. None of children should be able to mutate the logic inside any method. They are only able to add something. It is a SOLID principle: > Software entities ... should be open for extension, but closed for modification.